# Creating a bootable disc from an ISO file

Tags: multi-boot, operating-systems, iso-image, bootable-media

I am trying to create a bootable DVD disc from an ISO file I downloaded from this website: [Ye Olde SteamOSe](http://directhex.github.io/steamos-installer/?r3). My goal is to dual boot this OS on a desktop(32-bit) I have, but I haven't been able to boot from the disc yet. I've been working on this for a couple months now I've tried quite a few things on my own, I've asked a few other computer science majors from my school, one of them had dealt with boot discs before and tried working with it for several hours with me but couldn't figure it out, and I just want to know what I've been doing wrong (and get this to work because I think it would be awesome!). So if anyone can help me and be as descriptive as possible that would be great! I am also very open to downloading any free software necessary to doing this well.

Comment: The bootable functionality is in the ISO file - you don't need to do anything.  Just burn the ISO image to a DVD (as an IMAGE not as a file) and boot off the disk - you may need to adjust your BIOS settings to boot the DVD, or press a button during bootup (often F12) to select the boot device.

Comment: It might help if you tell us what you tried and how that failed.

Comment: What's your current Operating System? (windows/MAC/linux)??

Comment: Can you grab i.e. Ubuntu and burn that onto a disk and try booting from it?

Comment: @ISAAC My current OS is windows 7 on my laptop or xp (i know it's crazy but i got it free rather than paying for 7) on my desktop.  I've tried burning to a dvd multiple times with different programs and when i try booting from the dvd it just says it can't boot from it. I haven't tried much yet with a usb though.

Comment: @Tim.DeVries Open the ISO with "Winrar" and look for "autorun.inf" in root(not in any sub-folder), and open it and make sure *.exe specified, does exist in the same location. autorun.inf is important to invoke the boot.

Comment: @ISAAC yes autorun.inf is there and it says in the code `open=setup.exe`.

Comment: Try to burn the ISO with "UltraISO portable" or Nero or with similar programs.. give it a try. Google it for "ultraiso portable free".

Comment: @ISAAC thanks! I'll try that when I get home from work.

Answer (score 3):

According to their web site you

> Just burn the ISO to a blank DVD from your favourite tool, and boot it.

Burn the ISO-image (as a whole) and not the extracted file system.

You didn't say what your current OS is, but in any case I'd suggest using an USB stick (if your system can boot from USB). The website contains instructions for Mac, linux and Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I will expand guntbert's answer (and do a little hand-holding) with this:

Burn an ISO image [**on Windows**](http://www.imgburn.com/).

On linux:

```
wodim -v -eject -data -tao dev=/dev/sr0 speed=4 "your_iso_file.iso"
```

You may need to install the `wodim` package:

```
yum install wodim
```

or

```
apt-get install wodim
```

Alternatively, as guntbert suggests, you may want to make a bootable USB stick, for that you will need to **extract the contents** of the iso to the **root** of a stick, you can use **WinRAR** to open an ISO, or you can mount (open) it directly if you're on Windows 8 or any modern Linux distro to copy its contents to the stick.

You may have to toggle the stick's bootable flag, so:

**Windows**:

1. Right click on `Computer` and select `Manage`.
2. Select the `Drive management` section.
3. Wait for the daemon to connect and select your USB drive.
4. Right click on it and select `Properties` or `Partition options`.
5. Look for a flag that says `bootable` and select it.

**Linux**:

1. Install `gparted`.
2. Open it and select the drive you want to make bootable.
3. Click `manage options`.
4. Select the `boot` flag and close the dialog.